# does python detect code snippets that are useless? (dead code elimination)

Tags: python

If I code something like this:

```py
for _ in range(100_000_000):
    a = 10
    b = 20
    c = a + b
    d = c * 2     
    e = d / 2
    del a, b, c, d, e
print("Hello World")
```

Will Python compiler realize it is useless and that there is no need to do anything? I've heard gcc can understand that but not Python.

My tests confirm that but I'm looking for a confirmation since I've stumbled across posts like this (https://bugs.python.org/issue1346214) that make me wonder if it's actually implemented. It's a very old version of Python and I'm using 3.11.1 but if they were already talking about it, I'm sure if they were to implement it it's now implemented?

On my laptop, the python code takes 0.07 seconds to run against 0 seconds for just the hello world which is why I think there is no dead code elimination.

Comment: No, CPython doesn't do this. You can use the disassembler to check (`dis.dis`)

Comment: The only actually dead code here is the `del` statement.  The three previous lines can have observable side-effects, for example if `a` was an object with a `__add__()` method.

Comment: I guess, but given how the `__add__()` method of integers objects is coded, there is no side-effect, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not eliminate the useless code, and you can prove it to yourself - compare the disassembled code in `slow` vs that in `fast` and you'll see it does indeed do all those useless computations. You can also verify they're being run using `timeit`. This only applies to `cpython` though - other implementations of python may optimize this (as you can see below with `numba`'s python subset!)

```
import dis
import timeit
def slow():
    for _ in range(100_000_000):
        a = 10
        b = 20
        c = a + b
        d = c * 2
        e = d / 2
        del a, b, c, d, e
    print("Hello World")

def fast():
    print("Hello World")

print(timeit.timeit('slow()',number=1000,globals=globals()))
dis.dis(slow)
print("*****")
print(timeit.timeit('fast()',number=5,globals=globals()))
dis.dis(fast)
```

Yields:

```
39.3209762
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (100000000)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                46 (to 56)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (_)

  4          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
             14 STORE_FAST               1 (a)

  5          16 LOAD_CONST               3 (20)
             18 STORE_FAST               2 (b)

  6          20 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             22 LOAD_FAST                2 (b)
             24 BINARY_ADD
             26 STORE_FAST               3 (c)

  7          28 LOAD_FAST                3 (c)
             30 LOAD_CONST               4 (2)
             32 BINARY_MULTIPLY
             34 STORE_FAST               4 (d)

  8          36 LOAD_FAST                4 (d)
             38 LOAD_CONST               4 (2)
             40 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
             42 STORE_FAST               5 (e)

  9          44 DELETE_FAST              1 (a)
             46 DELETE_FAST              2 (b)
             48 DELETE_FAST              3 (c)
             50 DELETE_FAST              4 (d)
             52 DELETE_FAST              5 (e)
             54 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            8

 10     >>   56 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print)
             58 LOAD_CONST               5 ('Hello World')
             60 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             62 POP_TOP
             64 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             66 RETURN_VALUE
```

```
*****
```

```
8.899999997424857e-06
 13           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello World')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you do want really ripping fast python with optimization, look at `numba`:

```
import numba as nb
import timeit

@nb.jit
def slow():
    for _ in range(100_000_000):
        a = 10
        b = 20
        c = a + b
        d = c * 2
        e = d / 2
    print("Hello World")

@nb.jit
def fast():
    print("Hello World")


print(timeit.timeit('slow()',number=5,globals=globals()))
print(timeit.timeit('fast()',number=5,globals=globals()))
print(slow.inspect_llvm()[tuple()])
print("****")
print(fast.inspect_llvm()[tuple()])
```

These will yield very similar LLVM code. There are a bunch of limitations that come with `numba` compiled code, though, which are out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any idea why some people are talking about dead code elimination in the link I provided? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @Carbon I think it's best to add a caveat that the answer is for CPython. Other implementations might do some optimisations - I don't believe the Python language specifications or PEPs forbid the optimisations.

Comment: @FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows the AST will try to optimize a bit withinin a statement - you can see, eg, that disassembling `def (a): return 1 + 2 + 3` will show a return of 6 directly. A lot of this is implementation dependent.

Comment: Following your comment saying the AST can optimize a tiny bit (and I'm super convinced since the output is literally is the same: https://i.imgur.com/znkP0gO.png), I used dis.dis to check if the `if 0:` statement was indeed ignored like the link I provided said, is the "NOP" I find means it is successfully ignored? https://i.imgur.com/Dd3qGQx.png

Comment: I would go on saying that the "NOP" adds compute time since timeit repeatedly shows a higher time with `if 0:`: https://i.imgur.com/lXA0mFH.png